# proper alignment of footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
   <div id="footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span5">
            <img src="../goyal/webdesign.jpg" class="verisign-image"></div> 
                I am a  
                <select style="width:10%;" class="dropup">
                      <option value="select">--select--</option>
                      <option value="Business">Business</option>
                      <option value="Indivisual">Indivisual</option>
                </select>

                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-Warning" style="margin-top:-1%;">Go!
                </button>   

                <div class="span5" style="float:right;">
                <div class="footer-feedback">
                    <p class="left">Add & claim your business link|
                        <a href="">link1</a>|
                        <a href="">link2</a>
                    </p>
                    <span class="footer-feedback">
                        <h5>Feedback</h5>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div><!--span5 --> 
        </div><!--span5 -->
    </div><!-- row -->
</div>
```

css:

```
div#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#eee;
}

/* IE 6 */
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
span.footer-feedback{

color:#fff;
float:right;
width:80px;
height:100%;
background:green;
}
 p.left {
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}

 p.right {

    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}
```

I want proper alignment in my footer.
like feedback in middle of green area.
and left side of green are i want this text "Add & claim your business link| link2 | link3"
in middle "i am a , select and go"
go button in orange color.
and my footer is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/S2hqy/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span5"><img src="../goyal/webdesign.jpg" class="verisign-image"></div> 
            <div class="orange">
                I am a  
                <select class="dropup">
                    <option value="select">--select--</option>
                    <option value="Business">Business</option>
                    <option value="Indivisual">Indivisual</option>
                </select>

                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-Warning" style="margin-top:-1%;">Go!</button>   
            </div> 
            <p class="left">Add & claim your business link|
                <a href="">link1</a>|
                <a href="">link2</a>
            </p>
            <div class="span5" style="float:right;">
                <div class="footer-feedback">

                    <span class="footer-feedback">
                        <h5>Feedback</h5>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div><!--span5 --> 
        </div><!--span5 -->
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   /*height:30px;*/
   width:100%;
   background:#eee;
   text-align:center;
   padding:5px 0;
}
select.dropup {
    width:200px;
    }
/* IE 6 */
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
span.footer-feedback{
color:#fff;
float:right;
width:80px;
height:100%;
background:green;
text-align:center;
}
 p.left {
    display:inline-block;
}

 p.right {

    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}
.orange {
    /*background-color:#ff9a2e;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;*/
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just Replace Your Css This Css

```
div#footer {
   position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    /*height: 30px;*/
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
}
```

Just remove height element from 'dif#footer' tag.